# Combining/merging variables in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am working within terraform and I am trying to combine variables.

I have been able to do this previously in the format of

```
name = "${var.name}-${var.environment}"

or something like 

domain = "${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
```

Now I am trying to accomplish something similar but my module that I would like to do this with is utilizing a for_each.

I am trying to specify a host using variables that would represent utility.environment.domain.

Module:

```
module "aws_alb_listener_rule" {
  depends_on = [
    module.aws_lb_target_group,
    module.aws_alb_listener_https
  ]
  source = "../../terraform/modules/aws_lb_listener_rule_https"
  listener_rule = module.aws_alb_listener__https.lb_listener
  for_each = var.target_group_listener_rule_values

  listener_rule_host_header  = "${each.value.host_header}.${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
  #listener_rule_host_header = each.value["host_header"]

  listener_rule_target_group = module.aws_lb_target_group[each.key].arn
  listener_rule_action_type  = each.value["action_type"]
```

Where the first host header is what I was hoping to include but the commented out host header is how I currently have it.

My variables:

```
variable "target_group_listener_rule_values" {
  description = "Specify the target group and listener rule settings and it will create on a 1:1 ratio"
  type = map(object({
    /*--- Listener Rule ---*/
    host_header  = list(string)
    #host_header = string
    target_group = string
    action_type  = string
```

my tfvars

```
listener_rule_values = {
  Utility1 = {
    /*--- Listener Rule ---*/
    "host_header" = ["utility"],
    #"host_header" = ["utility.environment.domain"],
    "action_type" = "forward",
},
  Utility2 = {
    /*--- Listener Rule ---*/
    "host_header" = ["utility"],
    #"host_header" = ["utility.environment.domain"],
    "action_type" = "forward",
},
```

Where the first host header is what I was hoping to include but the commented out host header is how I currently have it.

Child module:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
  listener_arn = var.listener_rule


  action {
    type = var.listener_rule_action_type
    target_group_arn = var.listener_rule_target_group
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = var.listener_rule_host_header
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is shift this over to use variables instead as I am trying to remove the environment from being entered anywhere in the config except for the "environment" variable.

```
listener_rule_host_header  = "${each.value["host_header"]}.${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
```

the error I am seeing is

```
Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on main.tf line 181, in module "module":
│  181:   listener_rule_host_header  = "${each.value["host_header"]}.${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value["host_header"] is list of string with 1 element
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Answer (score 0):

you are very close and your syntax for interpolation is correct. What is not correct is the fact that your `each.value["host_header"]` is a list, so Terraform complains about that.

I don't know why you want a list, and You did not give your full code, so let me show you a working example with map, that I imagine you want to accomplish:

```
variable "environment" {
  default = "stage"
}

variable "domain" {
  default = "example.com"
}

variable "sites" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    "utils" = {
      "host_header" = "utility"
    }
    "main" = {
      "host_header" = "www"
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "hosts" {
  for_each = var.sites
  filename = "${each.value.host_header}.${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
  content = each.key
}
```

You can adjust your code based on this example, I hope.

Now, if you insist on using lists, this would look like this:

```
variable "sites_with_list" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    "utils" = {
      "host_headers" = ["utility"]
    }
    "main" = {
      "host_headers" = ["www"]
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "hosts_list" {
  for_each = var.sites_with_list
  filename = "${each.value.host_headers[0]}.${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
  content = each.key
}
```

I did not know how you want to utilize this, so I used a local_file just as an example that will work when copied to empty project.

Comment: So I tried what you mentioned but I was still receiving the same errors.

I have updated my original post to be more descriptive with more code included.

For my "host_header" variable I have tried different variations of types but it seems to produce more errors depending on what is keyed in.

For my variable type I am using a map(object) as well, which may change things.